# When scrolling my dataview vertically, after releasing thumb it automatically scrolls back to the top

Tags: sencha-touch

I have a dataview and when scrolling it vertically, after releasing thumb it automatically scrolls back to the top. Whereas with a list it would stay where you release the thumb.

Is this something inherent within a dataview component that cannot be avoided or is there some kind of configuration parameter I can tweak?

My current definition:

```js
informationdataview = new Ext.DataView({
    id: 'informationdataview',
    itemSelector: 'div.thumb-wrap',
    tpl: informationtpl,
    autoHeight: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    store: myapp.stores.information,
    scroll: 'vertical'
});
```

And it's the only item inside an `Ext.Panel`.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this code to my app.js file solved my similar problem:

```
Ext.define('Override.util.PaintMonitor', {
override: 'Ext.util.PaintMonitor',
constructor: function (config) {
    return new Ext.util.paintmonitor.CssAnimation(config);
}});

Ext.define('Override.util.SizeMonitor', {
override: 'Ext.util.SizeMonitor',
constructor: function (config) {
    var namespace = Ext.util.sizemonitor;

    if (Ext.browser.is.Firefox) {
        return new namespace.OverflowChange(config);
    } else if (Ext.browser.is.WebKit || Ext.browser.is.IE11) {
        return new namespace.Scroll(config);
    } else {
        return new namespace.Default(config);
    }
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, which was fixed by putting the layout value for main Panel to hbox. This is already covered in a separate question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194463/2-scrolling-lists-in-sencha-touch-dont-scroll).

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that, there is scroll view configuration mistake. Refer here for a better solution. 
[UIScrollView Controller not scrolling fully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36673746/uiscrollview-controller-not-scrolling-fully)

Comment: This is a guess, it should be posted as comment not as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am also faced same issue i got the solution. U have set snapboundary for dataview (i.e) set top and bottom as 0, and sibling component should be docked top if u have any. Important thing make `height: 100%` not in pixels

```js
items: [{
    xtype: 'selectfield',
    docked: 'top'
}, {
    xtype: 'dataview',
    width: '100%',
    bottom: 0,
    top: 0,
}]
```